# To get sum threw Looping

Tags: python, loops, filter, data-science

i have list of states in a list,i want to filter 
get all states group by & 
sum of total loan requested by state &
sum of total loan funded to the state
i am using below code please guide me where i am wrong & what i can do to make it better.
This is what i tried

```py
vest=fine['States'].unique()
st_share=fine[(fine.States==va) & (fine.loan_amnt)&(fine.funded_amnt)]
st_share
```

variables are

```py
fine=>is dataset name
vest=>list of all states

fine[(fine.States==vest) & (fine.loan_amnt)&(fine.funded_amnt)]
```

Comment: This looks like a [tag:pandas] or perhaps [tag:numpy] question. Please [edit] your question to add the corresponding tag(s) for any third-party library, and also mention this in the text of the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

To group and sum `loan_amnt` and `funded_amnt` by `states` you need to use a pandas function:

```
st_share = fine[['states', 'loan_amnt', 'funded_amnt']].groupby('states').sum()
```

You may also want to add `.reset_index()` at the end of the statement, if you don't want the `states` field to be the new index.

Comment: i am getting error 'states' not in index  as you defined so now for particular state i have to define index or before grouping

Comment: hi. can you show me the exact code you are running, that gave you that error?

Comment: And also pay attention whether you have "States" (with a capital 'S') or "states", as python is case-sensitive.